# How can create Serializer with custom logic?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Only *two parameters* come to the input:

1. param1 = Int, optional
2. param2 = Char, require

On output - `json` with *4 elements*

1. key1 = Char
2. key2 = Int
3. key3 = Int
4. key4 = Int

Everything can be null

Now I have it implemented in the view in the `get method`, but I want to create a `Serializer` for this and put all the logic there, but I don’t really understand where to transfer the logic - `validate`, `to_representation`?

Now it looks something like this

**views.py**

```
class ExampleRetrieveApiView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # A lot of logic related with input parameters.
        return Response({
            'key1': value1,
            'key2': value2,
            'key3': value3,
            'key4': value4
        })
```

Need to do something like this

**views.py**

```
class ExampleRetrieveApiView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ExampleSerializer(???)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**views**

```
class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ExampleSerializer(data=request.query_params)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return(Response(serializer.data))
```

**serializers**

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    param1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    param2 = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        #custom logic
        data['param3'] = 'text'
        #another params
        return data

    def to_representation(self, data):
        return {
            'key1': data['param3']
            'key2': data['param4']
            #another key for representation
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the input params as a dict. Then, you should use SerializerMethodField() for this:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
  key1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  key2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  key3 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  key4 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_key1(self, obj):
    # do some calculations, let's say we want to return input1 multiplied by 2
    # I'm accessing obj data and if it's empty assigning 0, you can add your own check instead
    return obj.get('input1', 0)*2

  def get_key2(self, obj):
    # same deal, do whatever calculations you want with the input data
    return obj.get('input2')

  def get_key3(self, obj):
    # your logic
    return

  def get_key4(self, obj):
    return
```

For every field declared as SerializerMethodField, you should have a corresponding get_field method.

It's up to you how to get the input params, you can do it either through query params or body data.
Call the serializer like this in your view, for example with body params:

class ExampleRetrieveApiView(APIView):

```
def get(self, request):
    input_data = {'input1':request.data.get('input1'),
                  'input2':request.data.get('input2')}
    serializer = ExampleSerializer(input_data)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: That works too, but personally I wouldn't implement logic in validate that's actually used to calculate/transform the input. The purpose of validate is to validate the input in some non-standard way. In your case you're actually transforming the input into something different.